# Animation of different images in list

Tags: android

I have different images, say 100 images or so. Now, I want to apply animation on them. I want my ImageView to get each image after specified interval but when the change of image occurs, each image should FadeIn or FadeOut. I place my images in @drawable/[list_of_images].xml file as:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a1" android:duration="1000"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a2" android:duration="2000"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a3" android:duration="3000"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/a4" android:duration="500"/>
```

and then I can successfully change these images depending on their time interval in ImageView by using:

```
public class AnimTest extends Activity
{
   AnimationDrawable myAnim;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.anim);

       ImageView myIV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
       myIV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.list_of_images.xml);

       myAnim = (AnimationDrawable) myIV.getBackground();

   }

  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
  {
      if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
      {
         myAnim.start();
         return true;
      }
     return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
```

}

The problem is that I can't figure out on how to apply fade effect on every single image, while they are getting changed by the above animation. I can apply fade animation on whole list of images but cannot do this on every image. Am i going to the right direction to achieve this functionality? If not, please guide me to the right path.

Regards,
Khawar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try setting a repeat count on your Animation to imagecount-1, then adding an AnimationListener to your animation that changes the background image of the ImageView on every repeat and on start.

Here's a simple example that uses RoboGuice (which makes the code cleaner but doesn't make any difference for the purposes of your question): https://github.com/bostonandroid/batgirl/blob/master/src/org/roboguice/batgirl/Batgirl.java

```
public class Batgirl extends RoboActivity {
    // Views
    @InjectView(R.id.content) LinearLayout linearLayout;

    // Resources
    @InjectResource(R.anim.spin) Animation spin;
    @InjectResource(R.integer.max_punches) int MAX_PUNCHES;

    // Other Injections
    @Inject ChangeTextAnimationListener changeTextAnimationListener;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Set up the animation
        linearLayout.setAnimation(spin);
        spin.setAnimationListener(changeTextAnimationListener);
        spin.setRepeatCount(MAX_PUNCHES - 1);

        spin.start();
    }
}

/**
 * A simple animation listener that swaps out the text between repeats.
 */
class ChangeTextAnimationListener implements AnimationListener {
    @InjectView(R.id.hello) TextView helloView;
    @Inject Fist fist;
    @Inject PackageInfo info;

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
        onAnimationStart(animation);
    }

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        helloView.setText( getNextTextString() );  // getNextTextString() not shown in this example
    }

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {            
    }
}
```